# Installshield does not import the .reg file(s)

Tags: registry, installshield

My simple installshield project needs to import registry files. How do I do that during the installation?
All I have done for these .reg files is create a component for each in IS and import the reg file into the registry view using the wizard.
When I build the installshield project and run it on a machine my result is the .reg files exist, but they are not being imported into the registry.
Manually I do this by going to the directory and executing the .reg. For Example:
cd C:\EmulatorInstall
Dev64bit.reg

now the registry gets imported after that command?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your imported registry values are getting installed. Likely you built a 32bit MSI and the values are appearing under  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node... instead of HKLM\SOFTWARE...